# WPF Toolkit Data Grid , Selected Item Prevent changing

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

1. I have a WPF Toolkit DataGrid,
2. First Item is selcted
3. User clicks on any other item on the Grid
4. I do some validations (any validation on selection change event of the WPF Toolkit DataGrid)
5. If validations returns false
6. I want prevent User from changing the previously selected Item
7. I tried saving previous index in a variable and set it again but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

look at ICollectionView event Currentchanged, Currentchanging and the MoveCurrentTo methods.

```
 this.MyGridItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<MyDataItems>();
 this.view = (ICollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.MyGridItemsSource)
 this.view.CurrentChanging += your eventhandling goes here
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution, can i am not using MVVM pattern. It's normal three tier arch. I will check your solution. But just more details: I want to set selected item to the previous item in WPF DataGrid. Is there anything available like "Handled = true" ?

Comment: dont know if there is something like "e.handled=true" but if you know the previous item you can just use the view.MoveCurrentTo(mypreviousitem) method.

Comment: well another way to prevent the user from changing the datagridrow, would be to handle the previousmousedown and previouskeydown events, but this seems not the right way for me ;)